# PHP How can I pass values from one array to another?

Tags: php, arrays, dynamically-generated

I'm trying to pass some of the values from theOptions array and drop them into a new array called $theDefaults.

```
$theOptions = array(

    'item1' => array('title'=>'Title 1','attribute'=>'Attribute 1','thing'=>'Thing 1'),
    'item2' => array('title'=>'Title 2','attribute'=>'Attribute 2','thing'=>'Thing 2'),
    'item3' => array('title'=>'Title 3','attribute'=>'Attribute 3','thing'=>'Thing 3')

);
```

So, $theDefaults array should look like this:

```
$theDefaults = array(

    'Title 1' => 'Attribute 1',
    'Title 2' => 'Attribute 2',
    'Title 3' => 'Attribute 3'

);
```

However, I cannot figure out how to do this.
Have tried this but it is clearly not quite working.

> ```
> $theDefaults = array();
>
> foreach($theOptions as $k=>$v) {
>     array_push($theDefaults, $v['title'], $v['attribute']); 
> }
> ```

but when I run this...

```
foreach($theDefaults as $k=>$v) {
    echo $k .' :'.$v;
}
```

It returns this.
0 :Title 11 :Attribute 12 :Title 23 :Attribute 24 :Title 35 :Attribute 3

Looks to be soooo close, but why are the numbers in the array?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's even simpler than that:

```
$theDefaults = array();
foreach($theOptions as $v) {
    $theDefaults[$v['title']] = $v['attribute']; 
}
```

Comment: Noting that the issue is that `array_push` pushes all arguments after the first to the end of the array.

Comment: Oooops, beat me to it by few seconds. :)

Comment: wow. that was fast. Thanks! it worked. apparently i can declare your answer correct in 8 minutes.