# How to pass an array as a variable to a new function php

Tags: php, arrays, function

I'm trying to get my head around arrays. This a is a followup to previous question.
[PHP How can I pass values from one array to another?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15697292/php-how-can-i-pass-values-from-one-array-to-another)

So, I've figured out how to pass data from one array to another thanks to: [Explosion Pills](https://stackoverflow.com/users/454533/explosion-pills) but now i'm trying to take the array and pass it through to a new function and then create the new array within the new function. I'm guessing this is easier than it appears to be to me right now.

Here is the array:

```
$theSetup = array(

        'option1' => array('title'=>'my_title','label'=>'The Big Title','val'=>'NoneyoBizness'),
        'option2' => array('title'=>'my_watch,'label'=>'Big Watch','val'=>'Seiko'),
        'option3' => array('title'=>'facebook','label'=>'Facebook Page','val'=>'http://facebook.com/bigwatch'),

);
```

Here is my test function:

```
function testArray($theSetup) {
    foreach($theSetup as $v) {
        $defaultOptions[$v['title']] = $v['val'];
    }
    foreach($defaultOptions as $k=>$v) {
        echo $k .' : '.$v .'<br>';
    }
} 
testArray($theSetup);
```

After running the code I get an error: `undefined variable theSetup`

Comment: can you post the full code?, so we know the scope where you are creating $theSetup

Comment: Where have you defined `$theSetup`? If it is in a different scope/context PHP won't be able to find it.

Comment: This is a simple debugging problem.

Comment: Did you define the variable before or after you called the function?

Comment: you guys were right. it was a scope issue. i was trying to call it from outside of the original function. However, am going to edit the question because i need to figure out how to pass the array from one function to another

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a text editor that shows you when you have a mistake in your PHP code.

This works fine:

```
<?php
    $theSetup = array(

            'option1' => array('title'=>'my_title','label'=>'The Big Title','val'=>'NoneyoBizness'),
            'option2' => array('title'=>'my_watch','label'=>'Big Watch','val'=>'Seiko'),
            'option3' => array('title'=>'facebook','label'=>'Facebook Page','val'=>'http://facebook.com/bigwatch'),

    );

    function testArray($theSetup) {
        foreach($theSetup as $v) {
            $defaultOptions[$v['title']] = $v['val'];
        }
        foreach($defaultOptions as $k=>$v) {
            echo $k .' : '.$v .'<br>';
        }
    } 
    testArray($theSetup);
?>
```

This does not:

```
<?php
    $theSetup = array(

            'option1' => array('title'=>'my_title','label'=>'The Big Title','val'=>'NoneyoBizness'),
            'option2' => array('title'=>'my_watch,'label'=>'Big Watch','val'=>'Seiko'),
            'option3' => array('title'=>'facebook','label'=>'Facebook Page','val'=>'http://facebook.com/bigwatch'),

    );

    function testArray($theSetup) {
        foreach($theSetup as $v) {
            $defaultOptions[$v['title']] = $v['val'];
        }
        foreach($defaultOptions as $k=>$v) {
            echo $k .' : '.$v .'<br>';
        }
    } 
    testArray($theSetup);

?>
```

The difference is I closed your quote mark after "my_watch."

Output

```
This works fine: my_title : NoneyoBizness
my_watch : Seiko
facebook : http://facebook.com/bigwatch
```

Comment: Adobe DreamWeaver, NetBeans, Aptana, Komodo, Notepad++, and GUI versions of Emacs all have code syntax highlighting that will tell you when something unexpected happens in the code. Just like in your example on this page, it would show you that something wasn't quoted properly.